# IINSERT INTO in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

how can I declare an Insert Into in `HQL` `Hibernate`?, is it the same way as `sql`?

This is my code, that I need to migrate to hibernate:

```
DECLARE @variable int
SET @variable = (SELECT variable from entity WHERE description LIKE ('%Small%'))
```

Comment: You can not do it. See the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql) for the list of available facilities.

Comment: I could not found it @SternK, can you plese give a hand for see the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I solutioned the problem. I Just declare in the CONTROLLER an object and the save it.
example:

```
//create an new object of the Entity and save using JPA
Example example = new Example() ;
example.setFuncion();
ExampleRepository.save(example);
//done
```